# Changing the initial sub-dictionary when changing a new one, when copying with copy.copy(dict[dict])

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary of dictionaries that needs to be modified as the code progresses, but its original version will also be needed later. I know that if I just assign a new variable to a dictionary, a reference to the existing one will be created, and if I change either one of those objects, the other one will be changed as well.

I've also read here that to copy dictionaries, lists, etc you should use copy.copy, however, that doesn't work with my problem.

```
    from copy import copy
    a = {"1": {"1":2, "2":3}, "2":{"3":4, "4":5}}
    b = copy(a)
    b["1"].update({"4":3})
    # b == {"1": {"1":2, "2":3, "4":3}, "2":{"3":4, "4":5}}
    # a == {"1": {"1":2, "2":3, "4":3}, "2":{"3":4, "4":5}} Although "a" shouldn't change
```

I'm new to python, so could you please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake initially. The problem is that copy copies a reference to the sub object instead of the values. That's why you need deepcopy.

```
from copy import deepcopy
a = {"1": {"1":2, "2":3}, "2":{"3":4, "4":5}}
b = deepcopy(a)
b["1"].update({"4":3})
print(b)
print(a)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, it works, and also, I can save what was previously there by combining the two dictionaries. However, could you explain why `.update()` causes this problem?

Comment: @Aerocobra, You can use deepcopy. Copy only copied a reference to that sub object. Now the problem is fixed. Can you accept the answer now?

Comment: Can you accept it now?

Comment: Oh sure. Now I understand everything) Should I do something with the question to show that it is resolved?

Comment: @Aerocobra Yes, exactly, click on the checkmark besides my answer.